# pass category name instead of category_id in url in phpBB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, phpbb, phpbb3

i have this link in phpBB forums

```
 <a href="{forumrow.FORUM_NAME}" class="forumtitle">{forumrow.FORUM_NAME}</a>
```

which give me result in

```
    localhost/phpbb/viewforum.php?f=Your Category
```

but i want

```
     localhost/phpbb/viewforum.php?f=Your-Category
```

i have try **str_replace** with code but its not working.

what i have to do in phpBB??

i have not idea about this so help me ..

Answer (score 0):

use **urlencode();**. It will return encoded string. So You need to use **urldecode();** for decoding.

check it from [here](https://www.php.net/urlencode).

You can also use **base64_encode();**
check this from  [here](https://www.php.net/base64_encode).

Comment: the logic of  urlencode(); i know but i dont know how to write here like <a href="<?php urlencde{forumrow.FORUM_NAME} ?>"> or  <a href="<?php urlencde({forumrow.FORUM_NAME}) ?>"> its give blank href

Comment: I think this is Your template page and from You are passing forumrow. So from where You are passing this FORUM_NAME - You need to pass it into encoded format. In template file You can't encode it.